# Update my py2exe 0.69 to trunk

Tags: python, py2exe

I installed py2exe using the official release, but I was having problems with the generated exe, so I thougt I update it to trunk and see of it solves my problem, since the last release is more than 3 years old already (last modified 2008-11-16).
As stated [here](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=15583) you can get the source [here](https://py2exe.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/py2exe).

So my question is how should I proceed to update what I have installed with the latest version? should I just download the source and overwrite the installation folder?

Comment: I guess you need to build it first (there's a `build.cmd` file), and then install